# Flutter using Mixin correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking to create two widgets that are similar and therefore should share some code.

I have made.a mixin that looks like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

mixin WidgetShared <T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T>, TickerProviderStateMixin<T>{

  AnimationController controlsAnimationController;
  Animation<double> controlsAnimation;
  bool controlsOpen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("This was the init");

    controlsAnimationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400), vsync: this);
    controlsAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controlsAnimationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controlsAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void toggleControls(bool disableClicks) {
    if (disableClicks == false) {
      if (controlsAnimationController.value > 0) {
        setState(() {
          controlsOpen = false;
        });
        controlsAnimationController.reverse();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          controlsOpen = true;
        });
        controlsAnimationController.forward();
      }
    }
  }


  void closeControls() {
    if (controlsAnimationController.value > 0) {
      setState(() {
        controlsOpen = false;
      });
      controlsAnimationController.reverse();
    }
  }
}
```

Which both of the widgets use e.g.

```
class _Widget1State extends State<MediaViewer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin, SuperMediaViewer{
```

I can then reference the controlsOpen, controlsOpen and toggleControls()  in both widgets easily.

However if i keep changing switching pages on the app I get this error which originates in one of my Provider State objects.

```
I/flutter (31161): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (31161): The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for NewUserDetailsState:
I/flutter (31161): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
I/flutter (31161): This _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<NewUserDetailsState> widget cannot be marked as needing to build
I/flutter (31161): because the framework is locked.
I/flutter (31161): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
```

I am clearly not doing something right but I'm unsure what. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is related to using a mixin?  If you duplicated the mixin's code to your widgets, does the problem go away?

Comment: I think it was caused by something else... sorry i forgot to edit my question. Is the approach i have taken with the mixin correct then?